# Exception Error in mininet

Tags: python, mininet, pox

I have used Mininet to create a simple custom topology. It worked correctly When I was running it for the first time, but after that I received following error message:

**Exception: Error creating interface pair (s1-eth1,h1-eth0): RTNETLINK answers: File exists**

what is it and how can I solve it?

here is my topology:

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet


class CustomTopo (Topo):

    def build(self):

        S1 = self.addSwitch('s1')

        H1 = self.addHost('h1')
        H2 = self.addHost('h2')

        self.addLink(S1, H1)
        self.addLink(S1, H2)


topo = CustomTopo()
net = Mininet(topo)
net.start()

topos = {'mytopo': CustomTopo}
```

and for more information I use Mininet 2.3.0d1

I run it by following command without remote controller and received another error:
**sudo mn --custom /home/bob/Desktop/Mtopo.py --topo=mytopo --mac**

the error is:
**Exception: Please shut down the controller which is running on port 6653**

I checked **netstat -nl | grep 6653** but there is no active session on port 6653 and there is no other controller to shutdown.

Comment: try cleaning by issuing:
sudo mn -c

Comment: I did it Daniel, but the error still remains

Comment: The code is fine (I had no problem running it). Do you run the code with sudo (as root) ?

Comment: @Daniel
yes I run it as root with : **sudo mn --custom /home/bob/Desktop/Mtopo.py --topo=mytopo --mac --controller=remote** I totally get confused and do not know what I have to do.

Comment: @Daniel
I found out that my topology create each host twice, so it can not add link between s1 and h1 for the second time. What do I have to do to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually start Mininet twice. Once in your script and the other with the command line.
Either change your script to:

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.node import RemoteController

class CustomTopo (Topo):

    def build(self):

        S1 = self.addSwitch('s1')

        H1 = self.addHost('h1')
        H2 = self.addHost('h2')

        self.addLink(S1, H1)
        self.addLink(S1, H2)


topo = CustomTopo()
net = Mininet(topo, controller=lambda name: RemoteController(name, ip='127.0.0.1', protocol='tcp', port = 6633), autoSetMacs=True)
net.start()
CLI(net)
net.stop()
```

save to start_topology.py and run as

```
sudo python start_topology.run
```

or change your script to

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.cli import CLI


class CustomTopo (Topo):

    def build(self):

        S1 = self.addSwitch('s1')

        H1 = self.addHost('h1')
        H2 = self.addHost('h2')

        self.addLink(S1, H1)
        self.addLink(S1, H2)


topo = CustomTopo()
topos = {'mytopo': CustomTopo}
```

save to mytopo.py and run as

```
sudo mn --custom mytopo.py --topo=mytopo --mac --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1,port=6633
```

(change the IP and PORT for your controller accordingly)

Comment: Your answer is complete, thanks. I chose your first solution, just one question, in this case how can I assign MAC address to hosts? I mean exactly like when I use **sudo mn --mac**, I do not want random MAC address.

Comment: You should add the parameter autoSetMacs=True to the Mininet constructor.
I have edited my answer to include this.

Comment: So I can use all parameters [http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1net_1_1Mininet.html#a2b42ae2e15dceca476abf8ed9573834c] in constructor. Thanks a lot @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

use this library:

```
from mininet.link import TCLink, Intf
```

and this when you add a link:

```
self.addLink(s1, h1, cls=TCLink)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the error still remains, I also use 
    'sudo mn -c' 
but nothing happen.

Comment: can you provide more details about using the script and the topo?

Comment: Sure, you can see the script in main question and I saved it as Mtopo.py in desktop. To run it I use following command:

**sudo mn --custom /home/bob/Desktop/Mtopo.py --topo=mytopo --mac** 
if you want more details, let me know what those are.
@dside